# What is the difference between the PATH listed by 'env' in git-bash and the PATH in Windows 10's control panel?

Tags: shell, path, environment-variables, git-bash

My goal is to write a shell script that will ensure that a bunch of Windows 10 computers with Python freshly installed on them can run the 'python' command from a git-bash command line in Windows Terminal by having the script check the PATH environment variable and modify it if necessary.

More specifically, I want my script to check if the following three paths are part of each computer's PATH, and if they aren't already a part of it, edit the PATH so that it permanently contains them.

1. C:\Program Files\Python311
2. C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts
3. C:\Users\ <localUser>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts

What threw me off is that I noticed that the PATH variable that I get from the 'env' command on the git-bash command line is different from the PATH variable that I can see in Windows 10's control panel. I tried adding a junk path to PATH from the command line by typing
`export PATH=/c/someNonexistentPath` in git bash but it didn't change the PATH that I could see in the Windows 10 control panel. Moreover, I couldn't even see if it changed the PATH I get from running `env` on the command line because for some reason after you run any `export` command git-bash gets amnesia and refuses to recognize the `env` command until you start a new session of git-bash.

Shouldn't there only be one PATH on a computer? If the two seemingly different PATHs that I have mentioned are not supposed to be the same, what is the difference between them, and how can I accomplish my goal of writing the script so that it does what I need it to do?

Please let me know if I need to include any more system-specific info. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: By and large, they should be independent, not the least because their syntax is different. I have never worked with _git-bash_, and I **could** imagine that a new bash process initializes PATH by converting it into a bash PATH; at least the Cygwin implementation of _bash_, which I am using, is doing this. The PATH is certainly not something "unique for the whole computer". This would be a bad idea: Think of running several processes in parallel, where you want them to use a different PATH setting. The Windows PATH settings provide an initial PATH value for the processes.

Comment: Correct, using the export command does not alter the system path variable. This would be true (with different syntax) in a cmd.exe shell also. Such definitions affect the current shell session only. I'm not sure why you are worried - gitbash will usually find the system python as it includes system PATH locations in its settings (I've never had any issues).